# Perform a descriptive statistical analysis and interpret your results.

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics

The following list gives the academic rank of the 25 female faculty members at a small liberal arts college, where L represents lecturer, F represents full professor, A represents assistant professor, T represents tutor, and AP represents associate professor.
-Perform a descriptive statistical analysis for the above data and hence interpret your results.

After the calculation, I got 8 assistant professors, 5 associate professor, 2 professor, 6 lecturer and 4 tutors. I construct a frequency distribution table, get the frequency, cumulative frequency and the percentages. The mode is AP which 8 is the highest number. Is there anything else I need to do for the descriptive statistical analysis? I'm not really understand the term descriptive statistical analysis and the interpretation.

Comment: Yes, I think you have the right idea.Usually you calculate the mean, the variance and draw a histogram.

Comment: But mean, variance, histogram inappropriate for categorical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems these might be ordinal categories: maybe T, L, A, AP, F.
That would make it possible to find the median category.

I have always considered some sort of graphical description to
be part of a descriptive statistical analysis. Here, your choices
are bar and pie chart. One style of bar chart below made using R statistical software.

[image]

In case you're interested, here is the code. R is available free
from `www.r-project.org`.

```
 g = c(4,6,8,5,2); nam =c("T", "L", "A", "AP", "P")
 barplot(g, names.arg=nam, col="blue")
 abline(h=1:7, col="white")
```